# best http server application as webdav?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, lighttpd, webdav

what is the best http server to be used as webdav for getting and posting files (big files) to from server?

is it apache or lighttpd ?

I will use the system as online file storage (for backup)

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is quite subjective but wouldnt setting up an FTP server suit your needs better? Possibly try FileZilla Server.

If you are hosting files also then apache wouldnt be a bad choice for you.

Comment: http/s is my best choice because it works behind any firewall

Comment: Sure it makes sense. What language would you build your application in?

Comment: mostly will be c#

Answer (score 0):

Open source solution is [WebDAV VFS gate](https://github.com/a-langer/webdav-vfs-gate), supported features:

1. Available all file systems of Apache Commons VFS (smb,ftp,sftp,http,webdav,zip,jar and other).
2. WebDAV (level 1 and level 2) compatible with Windows Explorer, GVFS and davfs2.
3. Server implemented as library (jar) and web application (war).
4. Application ready for use in web containers, such as Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss and similar.
5. Configuring file system from servlet initialization parameters and java properties.
6. Audit log of file operations.